# Issue with Internet Explorer 8 not loading CSS for two elements with the same class

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, internet-explorer

I have two Bootstrap navs on one page. One is at the top of the page and the second is lower on the page. I have custom CSS for the navs, but they use the same classes and the same CSS.

The problem is that the first nav in Internet Explorer 8 has no CSS and I don't know why.

Here is a sample of the code: [JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/c1jhwLy3/1/)

Here is the full code:

```
<nav class="nav">
    <ul>
        <li>
            <a href="#Services" data-scroll="1300">
                <i class="icon-multideal prepend"></i>
            &nbsp;Services <i class="icon-arrow-right append"></i>
            </a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#Company" data-scroll="1300">
                <i class="icon-company prepend"></i>
            &nbsp;Company <i class="icon-arrow-right append"></i>
            </a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</nav>

<nav class="nav" style="padding: 0 0 20px 0;">
    <ul>
        <li>
            <a href="https://maps.google.com?daddr=" target="_blank">
                <i class="icon-pointer-3 prepend"></i>
            &nbsp;Route <i class="icon-arrow-right append"></i>
            </a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="http://link.com">
                <i class="icon-window-home prepend"></i>
            &nbsp;Company page <i class="icon-arrow-right append"></i>
            </a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="http://www.google.com" target="_blank">
                <i class="icon-globe prepend"></i> Website <i class="icon-arrow-right append"></i>
            </a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</nav>

.nav {
    padding: 20px 0;
}

.nav ul {
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0;
    border: 1px solid #e0e0e0;
    border-top: 0 hidden;
}

.nav ul li {
    display: block;
}

.nav ul li a {
    border-top: 1px solid #e0e0e0;
    display: block;
    padding: 15px;
    background: #fff;
    color: #333;
    font-weight: 600;
    cursor: pointer;
    text-decoration: none;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    -o-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
}

.nav ul li a .prepend {
    font-size: 24px;
    margin: 0 10px 0 0;
    line-height: 0;
    vertical-align: sub;
}

.nav ul li a .append {
    line-height: inherit;
    vertical-align: sub;
    float: right;
    margin-top: 5px;
}
```

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Your import statement (in your fiddle, which you omitted here) appears to be malformed: `@import("https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css")` The parentheses should be removed and there should be a semicolon at the end.

Comment: @Boltclock is right. The problem with IE8 is that it doesn't recognise nav as a block; the Bootstrap stylesheet takes care of that. If you include it properly!

Comment: @BoltClock It is not the Bootstrap CSS that is the problem, in the fiddle I just imported the CSS for Bootstrap. In the real project the Bootstrap is in another CSS file and all the CSS in minified in one desktop.min.css file. Bootstrap is not the problem. In Internet Explorer 9, 10 and 11 it works perfect. The only problem is in Internet Explorer 8

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem isn't the `nav` tag only, but all HTML5 tags. IE8 doesn't know HTML5, that's why there is a generic solution for that, called HTML5 Shiv:

- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTML5_Shiv
- https://github.com/aFarkas/html5shiv

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that the "nav" is not supported in Internet Explorer 8. Therefore I have added the following code in the :

```
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
    <script>
        document.createElement('nav');
    </script>
<![endif]-->
```

Now it is working